# php-fpm Socket spawns with bad chmod

Tags: centos, php

Everytime i restart my **php-fpm** it's creating or updates socket file to **chmod 660** and i need to change manually chmod to 666

I have done before listen to file **php-fpm.sock** instead of **127.0.0.1**

How to get rid of it?

**EDIT**

Done! I have uncommented ";listen.mode = 0666" and it works like a charm

Comment: Depending on usage, wouldn't it be more secure to manage groups of users needing access to php-fpm rather than allow everything?